# How to Split Title in Java

Tags: java, split

I tried to split below

String input = "Alison Quek Yong Hoon MRS Alison Teng Yong Hoon";
String[] output = input.split("(?<=(MRS\s|MRS\.))");

result i got :

1. Alison Quek Yong Hoon MRS
2. Alison Teng Yong Hoon

my expected result are :

1. Alison Quek Yong Hoon
2. MRS Alison Teng Yong Hoon

Comment: How are you seeing this result? Do you have `System.out.println()` or something in your code? If so, please [edit] your question to include that. In general, you should add enough code to your question so that anyone can compile and run it themselves to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The regexp you pass to `split` needs to *match* the entire 'thing that separates'. In your case, you want it to match the M, the R, the S, and any spaces around it.

Your regexp instead matches 0 characters: It has nothing but lookbehind. It only matches that 0-char-sized position in the input which precedes MRS followed by precisely one space or one dot, because of the lookahead, but that's what is matched and thus removed, and therefore, 0 characters (nothing) is removed.

What you want is much simpler: `input.split("\\s*MRS[ .]")`.

This matches 'any amount of spaces, followed by MRS, followed by either a space or a dot'. It will then return everything in between what this matches, removing the stuff that matches (i.e. removing the 'spaces, MRS, space-or-dot' parts, and returning everything in between).

Comment: i tried this one. but MRS is gone. can we keep it? so, it will give output like 
1. Alison Quek Yong Hoon 
2. MRS Alison Teng Yong Hoon

Comment: Your regexp uses positive lookbehind. You want positive lookahead for that. So, `(?=)`, not `(?<=)`.

Answer (score 1):

Split on `\s+MRS\s+` and then prepend `MRS` to the second part of the split:

```java
String input = "Alison Quek Yong Hoon MRS Alison Teng Yong Hoon";
String[] parts = input.split("\\s+MRS\\s+");
parts[1] = "MRS " + parts[1];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));

// [Alison Quek Yong Hoon, MRS Alison Teng Yong Hoon]
```

If you really want to use a lookaround, then you should be using a positive *lookahead*:

```java
String input = "Alison Quek Yong Hoon MRS Alison Teng Yong Hoon";
String[] parts = input.split("\\s+(?=MRS\\b)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));

// [Alison Quek Yong Hoon, MRS Alison Teng Yong Hoon]
```

Comment: This one works!
Thank you so much.

Comment: If green checkmark to the left would be possible it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split it with a single regular expression, you can use this:

```regex
\s(?=MRS)
```

This is a single whitespace followed by the string "MRS", but "MRS" is not included in the match.

If you want to extend that by one or more whitespaces, you can use `\s+(?=MRS)`.

Tested in jshell:

```jshell
jshell> "Alison Quek Yong Hoon MRS Alison Teng Yong Hoon".split("\\s(?=MRS)")
$1 ==> String[2] { "Alison Quek Yong Hoon", "MRS Alison Teng Yong Hoon" }
```